# Motor and radiator problem will there be and damage to motor or anything

Tags: automatic-transmission

Hi guys ive got one question i was looking over this car i was going to buy and there was engine oil in the radiator i ask the guys why it was in there he said he didnt have enough coolant to fill it so he used engine oil so he topped up the radiator and topped overfill bottle with that do any damage the the motor long term or short term

I am looking it to this can and really need to know if there will be any major damage to anything if hes put oil in the radiator or even if theres a leak will there be any damage and what will i need to do to fix it thanks

Comment: Was this not answered in the [other question](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/25223/4152)?

Answer (score 7):

**NO GO**

You won't be able to tell if he is being honest.

Oil in a radiator is a sign of a blown head gasket.

A blow head gasket requires the following to repair if the head is ok and not warped.

- Remove all fuel injection or carburation.
- Remove intake manifold
- Remove exhaust and manifold
- Remove valve cover and cam sprockets (if it's an overhead cam)
- Remove various sensors or connecting wires
- remove head

Then do the work to verify the head is good and clean everything up.  Get the head rebuilt or do it yourself.  Hope the head isn't trashed.

Stay away from it.

I won't go into a morality speech of the seller other than, run from him and move on.